# Automatically leave insert mode after some time in IdeaVim

Tags: neovim, ideavim

In my [Neovim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)#Neovim) configuration, I use *autocmd* and *updatetime* to leave insert mode after some idle time. Unfortunately, IdeaVim does not support *autocmd*.

Is there another way to implement this behavior in [IdeaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim)?